# Can a hive reducer script give output to more than one tables?

Tags: hive

I wish to save some data which the reducer script (which is in php) accumulates over the course of its execution into another table (having a totally different schema). What is the best way to go about it?
Also, Can we write to a file from within a reducer?

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is to upload the data to HDFS via WebHDFS into the appropriate directory (http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/webhdfs.html / CREATE).

If it's more convenient you can also then expose it as a partition using WebHCatalog (http://hive.apache.org/docs/hcat_r0.5.0/resources.html / PUT ddl/database/:db/table/:table/partition/:partition)

It will then show up in the table you wanted to write it into.